# Winston for Node outputting to console but not to Loggly

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, loggly

I am using Winston for Node to output log lines to Loggly.  I have run into an issue that I cannot resolve where the log lines are being output to the console, but they never appear in Loggly. The funny thing, some of the log lines appear in Loggly and others do not.

Here is the console data:

```
info: Lambda: createCustomer(dev): Function called to create customer in DynamoDB. Attempt #1

info: Lambda: createCustomer(dev): Successfully created customer (6196434835540541440) on attempt #1 Attempting to create a ZOHO customer record

error: Lambda: createCustomer(dev): Error creating ZOHO customer (Enter a valid Customer Name). Attempting to delete customer (6196434835540541440) from FS database

info: Lambda: createCustomer(dev): FS customer (6196434835540541440) was successfully backed out.
```

Here is what appeared in Loggly:

```
2016-10-24 17:39:49.462 {"level":"info","message":"Lambda: createCustomer(dev): Function called to create customer in DynamoDB. Attempt #1"}

2016-10-24 17:39:49.792 {"level":"info","message":"Lambda: createCustomer(dev): Successfully created customer (6196434835540541440) on attempt #1 Attempting to create a ZOHO customer record"}
```

I can't figure out why the call to watson.log would output to the console, but never make it to Loggly.  Is it possible that my script is "ending" before watson.log is finished so it just aborts (this is a lambda function)?

**Simplified Code:**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => { 
    createCustomer(event, callback);
}

function createCustomer(event, callback) {   
    docClient.put(event.body, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            // code to try to create the customer 3 times then fail.
        }
        else {
            winston.log('info', 'This log line will output to both the console and Loggly.');

            updateCustId(event, data.customer_id, function(err, data) {
                if (err) 
                    winston.log('error','This will output to console but not appear in Loggly.');
                else 
                    winston.log('error','This will output to console but not appear in Loggly.');

                callback(null,  event.body.Item);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how script is ending ? Node process would normally process all of the event queue before terminating. Perhaps you are calling `context.succeed/fail` before the logs are flushed out. Also check if `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` is true.

Comment: I added some simplified code that illustrates the problem I am having.

Comment: It seems only `error` logs are not going to Loggly. Can you check how the winston `transport` for Loggly is configured ?

Comment: 'info' logs are being left out as well. You can see this in the example console data from the original post.  Both of the first 2 info log lines make it to Loggly, the next error and then info log lines do not. It has to be some sort of timing / event loop issue. If I add more code to execute before the callback call then all the log lines make it Loggly.

Comment: More info... I checked `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` and it was undefined. Setting it to true did not alter the results.  I am running this code locally using grunt-aws-lambda.

Comment: Might [this be the issue](https://gist.github.com/hassy/eaea5a958067211f2fed02ead13c2678) ? . Also, can you schedule the callback after current queue using `prosess.nextTick()` ?